# How to run npm install during VSTS Build

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, npm-install

I have setup a VSTS build for a .NET Core application and am having a problem getting the node_modules included in the generated artifact.  Below is the Build Pipeline
[image]

As I watch the build run I see it go through and do the restore of the node_modules, but after it finishes the build successfully I look in the artifact that it generates and I do see the node_modules directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean in the **Publish Build Artifacts** task, didn't it publish the `node_module` folder to server or share path?

Comment: The node_modules was not in Source Control, so the Publish step didn't have the node_modules in it.  The result of the NPM step was in the artifact, but not in the zip file, but as a separate directory and files.  I ended up getting this to work although it is probably not the right way, by doing 2 separate Azure Deploy steps, one that did the zip and one that did the node_modules

Comment: Shouldn't this work the way a NuGet restore works? As in `node_module` should not be included in check in, and the build should refresh and grab new versions based on what is in `package.json`?